# JavaScript, why the generator failed?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a simple generator to get the increased value by call `next`

```
> var gg = next_id();
> function* next_id() {

    var current_id = 1;
    yield current_id;
    current_id ++;
    return current_id;
}

> gg.next()
Object {value: 1, done: false}
> gg.next()
Object {value: 2, done: true}
> gg.next()
Object {value: undefined, done: true}
> gg.next()
Object {value: undefined, done: true}
```

Why this generator just generate 2 value?

And I changed the code

```
function* next_id() {

    var current_id = 1;
    while (1) {
        yield current_id;
        current_id ++;
    }
    return current_id;
}
```

It works, it really made me confused.

Comment: thats how generators work right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you only call `yield` once. It looks like this is what you are trying to do:

```js
function* next_id() {
  var index = 0;
  while(true)
    yield index++;
}

var gen = next_id();

console.log(gen.next()); 
console.log(gen.next()); 
console.log(gen.next());
```

Refer to the documentation of generators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop and discard the `return` statement, which ends the function, whereas [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) just stops the the execution of the generator.

In your edit, the `return` statement is *never reached*, because the loop runs forever.

```js
function* next_id() {
    var current_id = 1;
    while (true) {
        yield current_id;
        current_id++;
    }
}

var gg = next_id();

console.log(gg.next()); // { value: 1, done: false }
console.log(gg.next()); // { value: 2, done: false }
console.log(gg.next()); // { value: 3, done: false }
console.log(gg.next()); // { value: 4, done: false }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```